# move_base scrapes obstacles instead of staying clear

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having a situation where move_base's planning causes my robot to scrape against obstacles as it turns away from them.

What parameter should I change to ensure that move_base turns away from obstacles well before hitting them? I've tried increasing the clearing & inflation radii, and also expanding the robot footprint. I can include my yaml files if needed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11056/move_base-scrapes-obstacles-instead-of-staying-clear/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some parameters that I've modified to resolve this problem are:

- local_costmap/update_frequency (I noticed that the robot was entering the inflated radius before it had time to react)
- obstacle_range and raytrace_range for both costmaps (you must also overwrite this value for each sensor that you're using or they will take their default value instead).

Also, is your robot rectangular? If so, is the footprint rectangular as well?

Try those and see if they help at all.

~ Brian

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1